# UI won't update, when adding an item to an ObservableCollection with a Command (WPF, C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, treeview, icommand

I have a TreeView, where I want to add an item with a right click. Therefore I use a command, to insert a new item. 
The problem is now that adding/removing items won't be reflected in the UI and I don't know why.

The ObersavableCollections are hold in a property in my MainWindow

```
public static ObservableCollection<PlantObject> PlantObjects { get; set; }
```

The code works the way I want thus if I check the property and the item itself, it will be added but the TreeView will not reflect the changes. This can be shown by setting the ItemsSource of the TreeView null and then again to PlantObjects, which then displays the added item.

I'm pretty sure it the problem is that I add an item to the property "parents". But I don't know how to solve it.

You can see my Xaml and my Class below. NotifyPropertyChanged is implemented.

Thanks for any advice.

**XAML**

```
<TreeView Name="ContextTreeView" Margin="0,9.8,0.8,5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:MainWindow.PlantObjects} }">
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate   DataType="{x:Type local:PlantObject}" ItemsSource="{Binding PlantObjects}" >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu >
                            <MenuItem Header="Delete" Name="MenuItem_DeleteContextType" Command="{Binding DeleteContextTypeCommand}"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Insert new object above" Name="ContextMenuItem_InsertAbovePlantObject" Command="{Binding InsertAboveCommand}"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
```

**My Class**

```
public class PlantObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public PlantObject()
    {
        CreateInsertAboveCommand();
    }

    private bool _IsSelected;
    private PlantObject parent;
    private string name;

    public byte[] ParentID { get; set; }
    public byte[] ChildID { get; set; }
    public byte[] ObjectID { get; set; }

    private ObservableCollection<PlantObject> plantObjects = new ObservableCollection<PlantObject>();

    public PlantObject Parent
    {
        get
        {
            return parent;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != parent)
            {
                parent = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != name)
            {
                name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<PlantObject> PlantObjects
    {
        get { return plantObjects; }
        set
        {
            //ignore if values are equal
            if (value == plantObjects) return;

            plantObjects = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _IsSelected; }
        set
        {
            if (_IsSelected == value) return;
            _IsSelected = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public int? GetPosition(PlantObject plantObject)
    {
        int count = 0;

        foreach (var childObject in this.plantObjects)
        {
            if (plantObject == childObject)
            {
                return count;
            }
            count++;
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void Insert(int position, PlantObject plantObject)
    {
        Parent.PlantObjects.Insert(position, plantObject);
    }

    protected void Remove(PlantObject plantObject)
    {

     Parent.PlantObjects.RemoveAt(Parent.PlantObjects.IndexOf(plantObject));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #region commands


    #region InsertAbove Command
    public ICommand InsertAboveCommand
    {
        get;
        internal set;
    }

    private bool CanExecuteInsertAboveCommand()
    {
        return true;
    }

    private void CreateInsertAboveCommand()
    {
        InsertAboveCommand = new RelayCommand(InsertAbove);
    }

    public void InsertAbove(object obj)
    {
        //this.IsSelected = true;

        if (this.parent == null)
        {    //highest level

            MainWindow.PlantObjects.Insert(MainWindow.PlantObjects.IndexOf(this), new PlantObject {IsSelected = true, Parent = this.Parent });
            return;
        }

        int position = this.parent.GetPosition(this) ?? default(int);

        PlantObject newPlantObejct = new PlantObject { Parent = this.Parent, IsSelected = true };
        this.Insert(position, newPlantObejct);
    }

    #endregion

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static yourNameSpace:MainWindow.PlantObjects }}". if you bind like this, does adding items update the UI?

Comment: I set the ItemSource in my MainWindow when I generate my data with ContextTreeView.ItemsSource = PlantObjects. I tried editting it the way you suggested, deleting the code behind ItemsSource, but then nothing of the TreeView will be built.

Comment: why do you have a method called `NotifyPropertyChanged` if your class do not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: can you fix your code so that one can just copy paste? you added IsSelected 2 times, and PlantObjects 2 times, and Parent is missing

Comment: @Milan so is `PropertyChanged`

Comment: @appayipyip it implements INotifyPropertyChanged I just forget copying it

Comment: @Milan I fixed the issues you mentioned, better now? Even though to make copy paste work, I still have to edit the XAML ...

Comment: Why you do you have an implementation of `INotifyCollectionChanged` (**Collection**Changed) on a class that doesn't actually implement that interface?

Comment: how does this compile for you? you are calling CollectionChanged inside PlantObject, but PlantObject does not implement INotifyCollectionChanged, did you actually try to build this?

Comment: @EdPlunkett yeah was nonsens

Comment: `MainWindow.PlantObjects.Insert(MainWindow.PlantObjects.IndexOf(this)....`

Comment: @Milan I had to free the code from unnecessary parts, to actually reduce it to the problem. My fault, I had to check this code before. I'm cleening it up.

Comment: @EdPlunkett as you probably noticed I'm new to C#, can you explain why this is false?

Comment: Ok... I made a clean project with just the code above and it works. So the problem has to be somewhere else. With your criticism you have already helped a lot, thx.

Comment: @tickietackie If you were asking why I disliked the `MainWindow` stuff, it's considered poor practice for viewmodels to know about windows, and for them to reach out like that. Ideally, that bit of code would instead be done by parents passing an `Action<T>` to children, or by children exposing an event. **If that code is working, keep it the way it is**. But the next time you address a similar problem, I'd urge you to consider other approaches.